# One to many and many to one access in Django

Tags: python, django

I have 2 models:

```
from django.db import models

class Model1(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)

class Model2(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    mdl1 = models.ForeignKey(Model1)
```

I can access model1 via model2

```
m2 = Model2.get(...)
m2.mdl1 #  one Model1
```

Is there any way to perform the vise-versa access:

```
m1 = Model1.get(...)
m1. # get all Model2 that belong to m1
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the [backward relationship](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/db/queries/#following-relationships-backward):

```
m1.model2_set.all()
```